# points picked uniformly from sphere

Tags: probability

**Let a point $P$ at distance $X$ from the origin be picked according to uniform density with respect to volume in an $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $1$. Given $X$, let $Q$ at distance $Y$ from the origin be picked according to uniform density with respect to volume in the $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $X$. Find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$, and $E(Y|X)$ and $E(X|Y)$.**

I don't understand why I'm incorrect here.

Let $n=2$. What I said was (okay this is a little heuristic but it's the right idea) $f(x) dx \approx P(X\in dx) = \frac{\pi(x+dx)^2 - \pi x^2}{\pi} = 2x dx + o(dx)$ and therefore $f(x) = 2x$ for $x<1$.

Now $P(Y\in dy | X=x) \approx \frac{\pi(y + dy)^2 - \pi y^2}{\pi x^2} = \frac{2y}{x^2} dy + (dy)^2/x^2 = \frac{2y}{x^2} dy + o(dy)/x^2 \Rightarrow f(y|x)=\frac{2y}{x^2}$ for $0\leq y< x.$

Thus I get that the joint density is $f(x)*f(y|x) = 4y/x$ for $0\leq y < x < 1$ if $n=2.$

However, this is wrong according to my friend as it's supposed to be $n^2 y^{n-1}/x^n$ for the joint density (e.g. $4y/x^2$ for $n=2$).

Also another hint is saying to use Beta distributions, but I don't quite see where that would come in anyhow. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks right to me. As a check, we should be able to recover the PDF of $X$ from the joint PDF:

$$\int_{y=0}^xf(x,y)dy=f_X(x)=2x$$

which is true if $f(x,y)=4y/x$ , but not if $f(x,y)=4y/x^2$.